# Python- .count not saving variable as int but as 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, int

```
def reverse(num):
  digits = []
  leng = num.count
  num1 = int(num)
  n = 0
  while(n < leng):
    last = num1 % 10
    num1 = (num1 - last) / 10
    last = str(last)
    digits = digits.append(last)
    n = n + 1
```

When I run this block it gives an error on the line with the while loop, saying < is not valid between an 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'. How do I save leng as an int?

Comment: `count` is a method. Call it to get the length.

Comment: As the error says, count is a method. You need to *call* it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [TypeError: 'builtin\_function\_or\_method' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322534/typeerror-builtin-function-or-method-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Comment: What is `num.count` supposed to do? If you are trying to find length, you may use `len(str(num))` assuming you are passing a `int`

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to shahkalpesh if you are trying to find length, you may use `len(str(num))`
if you are passing a `int`.

The count() method is avaible for string `string.count(value)`. For string count() method returns the number of times a specified value appears in the string as documentation tells: [count() for string in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_count.asp).

The count() method is also avaible for list `list.count(value)` as documentation tells: [count() for list in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_count.asp)

So you have an error because you try to use the `<` operator between an integer and an object that not is an integer (or superior numeric class).