# Can I write codes to count the frequency of each integer, and then print each integer with its frequency?

Tags: python

Given a list of integers:
Write codes to count the frequency of each integer, and then print each integer with its frequency. (The order of the elements does not matter)
For example, for `n = [1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]`, the print out will be:

```
1 3
2 2
3 3
4 5
5 3
6 9
```

And make each two numbers in a row.
i.e. in the first row, 3 is the frequency of 1 in the list n

My code is like that, and it shows 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable:

```
n = [1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]

def question_7_1(n=n):
    count=0
    for i in n:
        if i==n.index[i]:
            count=count+1
            print(i,count)
```

Comment: To call a method you use the syntax `n.index(i)` not `n.index[i]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'builtin\_function\_or\_method' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322534/typeerror-builtin-function-or-method-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = [1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]

def question_7_1(n):
    dict ={}
    for j in n:
        count=1
        #print(j)
        if j in dict.keys():
            count = dict[j]
            count=count+1
            dict[j] = count
        else:
            dict[j] = count
    dict[j] = count
    #print(dict)
    return dict

result = question_7_1(n)
print(result)
```

output :

```
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 3, 6: 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing it in a comparatively easy to understand method.

```
n = [1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]

freq = {}
for i in n: 
    if i in freq: 
      freq[i] += 1
    else: 
      freq[i] = 1

print ("Count is :\n "+  str(freq))
```

This should return the integer and the count.

The error in your code is the use of `n.index[i]`. It should've been `n.index(i)`.

**Output:**

```
Count is :
 {1: 3, 3: 3, 2: 2, 4: 5, 5: 3, 6: 9}
```

For a better implementation, refer to the answer by @Sheri!

Answer (score -1):

Tons of ways of doing this some ways are:

**Solution1:**

```
n = [1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]
def question_7_1(n):
    myCountDict = {}
    for i in n:
        countOfaNum = n.count(i)
        myCountDict[i] = countOfaNum
    print(myCountDict)

question_7_1(n)
```

**Solution2:**
More effective and optimal:

```
a = [1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]
d = {x:a.count(x) for x in a}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{
 1: 3, 
 2: 2, 
 3: 3, 
 4: 5, 
 5: 3, 
 6: 9
}
```

Comment: Neither option is effective or optimal: both are O(n^2) approaches as `list.count()` scans the entire list each time.