# Text split into paragraphs and then into strings

Tags: python

I am using following code but getting error

```
import re
text = 'some big text'
sentences = re.split('some splitter',text)
nsentences=len(sentences)

substring=[]


for i in range(nsentences):
    substring.append[i]=re.split('some splitter',sentences[i]) #error line
    print(substring[i])
```

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment

Comment: you have to use insert if you want the item to be at a specific position in `substring`. `append` appends always at the end and is a function

Comment: substring.insert[i]=re.split('some splitter',sentences[i])

Same error

Comment: and insert is also a function, so use parenthesis not brackets. Maybe take a look: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'builtin\_function\_or\_method' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322534/typeerror-builtin-function-or-method-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you receive is because of the incorrect assignment for `list.append()`. 
You can perform the append/insert of `re.split('some splitter', sentences[i])` in `substring` in two ways:

Append:

```
for s in sentences:
    substring.append(re.split('some splitter', s))
```

Insert:

```
for i in range(nsentences):
    substring.insert(i, re.split('some splitter', sentences[i]))
```

For reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Or it might be better to use a comprehension: `substring = [re.split('some splitter', s) for s in sentences]`